# Short term for Probability of Type I error

Tags: definition

When comparing statistical tests, one often compares

1. the probability of committing a Type 1 error, and
2. the probability of not committing a Type 2 error.

While (2) can be concisely termed 'power', is there a concise term for the (1)?

(I don't think significance is the right term)

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_hypothesis_testing#Definition_of_terms.

Comment: The radar literature calls the two probabilities as the "false-alarm probability" and "false-dismissal probability" which terms I find easier to remember than the bland and unimaginative "Probability of Type 1 error" and "Probability of Type 2 error".

Comment: @whuber, I suppose by that link you are suggesting 'false positive rate'? But just like I prefer 'power' over 'sensitivity' because it sounds more generic (or discipline-independent), I still wonder if there is an equivalent term for (1). But thanks for the link anyway.

Comment: Specificity is the only one-word term I can think of. I don't find it memorable, so I just say "$1-\alpha$". Nobody gets confused about what that means.

Comment: A nominal size.

Answer (score 2):

The pithiest word I've seen is [*size*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Size_%28statistics%29)

Comment: mm....interesting. Do you have more references to peer-reviewed articles or textbooks that use this term?

Comment: @qoheleth see: http://www.indiana.edu/~statmath/stat/all/power/power.pdf and http://scholar.google.com/scholar?oi=bibs&hl=en&q=%22test+size%22

Answer (score 1):

1. Significance level $\alpha$, [see here](https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/mks/statmistakes/errortypes.html)
2. [Power](https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/mks/statmistakes/power.html) $1-\beta$, [sensitivity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_and_specificity#Sensitivity) or recall rate

Comment: as mentioned in my original question, I don't think 'significance' is the right term. Yes, $\alpha$ certainly coincides with the numerical value of (1), but I think it is describing the other side of the same coin. After all, there is nothing significant about rejecting a correct null hypothesis.